# How to retrieve all the file names under a nested folder structure in Data lake using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to list all the file names under a given folder in adls using metadata activity.

Folders can be nested so I have to traverse all of them till the leaf nodes.

For each- doesn't allow nesting so I used Until loop.

The problem I am facing is to constantly update the list of files with new files because I am unable to append array variable to another array variable.

Any better solutions please?

Comment: It's hard to retrieve all the file names in ADF.  Can you clarity what's the meaning of 'I am unable to append array variable to another array variable'? I think it can be done in ADF.

Comment: I tried to use metadata activity and this returns a json array [ {"name1":"abc" , "type1": "File"}, {"name" : "def", "type2": "Folder"}] .. tried to append it to a pipeline array variable but unable to do so

Comment: The error I get is : "can't append array to array variable"

Comment: This is because you directly append array variable to another array variable in Append variable activity. You need to loop one array and append it's item to another array. Or add an another array variable, then use union() function to combine two array in Set variable activity. Note that union() function will remove the duplicate item. You can try to create an azure function(http trigger) to retrieve all the file names. It would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Post an answer to end this question. It is complex to achieve this in ADF by using  Until loop. You can try to create an azure function and invoke it in ADF.

Answer (score 0):

we ended up using copy activity and landed it to ADLS.
Then mounted the ADLS to databricks and retrieved the file names.

Still testing out the complete ADF solution.